# Having same restful url with different Id type parameter in mvc core 2.0

Tags: c#, rest

I am having a url http://locahost/Payer/{PayerId}. Now I want to use the same url but with different parameter i.e. http://locahost/Payer/{PayerUniqueRefID}. I dont want to do condition check in my background code. 
What I am proposing is using Query string for other url like below.

http://locahost/Payer?payerID=1234

Is this correct way.

Comment: That seems confusing to me. Do both PayerId and PayerUniqueRefID uniquely identify a Payer or can a value for one of those ids be the same for multiple Payers?

Comment: They uniquely identifies each payer

Comment: I would choose one and use that ID for your http://localhost/Payer/{Id}. If you need to query by the other Id then you could use http://localhost/Payer?otherId=1234.

I recommend reading some articles on REST apis. This has some useful info - http://www.andrewhavens.com/posts/20/beginners-guide-to-creating-a-rest-api/ I don't know if this is the best example but following a standard is important.